# Agent forwarding with PECL ssh2 extension

Tags: php, ssh, pecl

Is it possible to activate agent forwarding when working with the PECL ssh2 extension (similar to the -A ssh commandline option)? I can't find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with phpseclib:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('System/SSH/Agent.php');

$agent = new System_SSH_Agent(); 

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('website.com'); 
$ssh->login('user', $agent); 

$ssh->read('[prompt']); 
$agent->startSSHForwarding($ssh); 

$ssh->write("ssh user@domain.tld 'ls -la'\n");
```